# Using the animate package without Adobe

Tags: beamer, viewers, animate

I'm looking to use the animate package in beamer to display animated graphics to my class, and I was wondering if it'd be possible for the animation to work on their Chromebooks. It seems Adobe isn't supported on ChromeOS, so is there any other alternative?

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429/animation-in-pdf-presentations-without-adobe-reader/) question seems relevant, but I don't have any movie files or gifs, just what I've made using the animate package in LaTeX.

I understand this is quite likely not possible, but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Per the animate documentation the other viewer which can run the animation is PDF-XChange Viewer

Comment: pdf-xchange  viewer did not run my animations inside PDF. Only Adobe PDF reader did.

Comment: **KDE Okular** supports animations made with pkg `animate`.

Answer (score 48):

### 1 `beamer` class document in SVG format

Think about giving up the PDF format in favour of SVG.

Animations run in all contemporary Web browsers, while Blink-based ones (Chromium, Chrome, Edge, Opera) have the best performance. Also run on mobile devices.

With SVG as output format, video and YouTube embeds are possible too, using package `media4svg`; see:  [MP4 in presentation in a non-broken way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595102/mp4-in-presentation-in-a-non-broken-way) . And even [animated Gif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580847).

**Click the image** to start presentation in the Web browser and **press <kbd>F11</kbd>** for full-screen. Navigate through slides with **<kbd>PgUp</kbd>** and **<kbd>PgDown</kbd>**, mouse left or right click, or mouse wheel.

---

[image]

---

Compile the example code with

```
latex svgbeamer
latex svgbeamer
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff2 --bbox=papersize --page=1- --linkmark=none svgbeamer
```

Example code `svgbeamer.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass[dvisvgm,hypertex,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{animate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% slide navigation via keyboard and mouse left-or-right-click/mouse wheel,
% mouse cursor autohide on idle; navigation symbols <--, -->
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\AddToHook{shipout/before}{\xdef\currentPageNumber{\inteval{\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+1}}}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
  \put(0,0){%
    \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
      \normalsize\color{structure!40!}%
      \ifnum\currentPageNumber>1%
        \href{\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber-1\relax}.svg}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \fi\hspace{0.5ex}%
      \ifnum\currentPageNumber<\PreviousTotalPages%
        \href{\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber+1\relax}.svg}{\faArrowRight}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowRight}%
      \fi%
      \hspace{0.5ex}%
    }}%
  }%
  \special{dvisvgm:raw
    <style>svg{cursor: none}</style>%
    <defs>%
    <script type="text/javascript">%
    <![CDATA[%
      var cursorTimer;%
      var downOnLink=false;%
      var downOnRoot=false;%
      function islink(tg){return (tg.tagName=='a') ? true : tg.parentNode ? islink(tg.parentNode) : false;};%
      function ismmedia(tg){return (tg.tagName=='video'||tg.tagName=='audio') ? true : tg.parentNode ? ismmedia(tg.parentNode) : false;};%
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){%
        if(islink(e.target)||ismmedia(e.target)||e.target.getAttribute('class')=='annot'){%
          e.target.style.cursor='pointer';}else{e.target.style.cursor='default';}%
        try{clearTimeout(cursorTimer);}catch(err){};%
        cursorTimer=setTimeout(function(){e.target.style.cursor='none';},3000);%
      });%
      window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){% capture right click
        if(!islink(e.target)&&!ismmedia(e.target)) e.preventDefault();%
      });%
      document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){%
        if(islink(e.target)||ismmedia(e.target)) downOnLink=true;%
        else downOnRoot=true;%
      });%
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){%
        if(downOnLink||!downOnRoot){downOnLink=false;return;}%
        downOnRoot=false;%
        \ifnum\currentPageNumber<\PreviousTotalPages
          if(!e.shiftKey&&e.button==0) document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber+1\relax}.svg');%
        \fi%
        \ifnum\currentPageNumber>1
          if(e.shiftKey||e.button>1) document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber-1\relax}.svg');%
        \fi%
      });%
      document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){%
        \ifnum\currentPageNumber<\PreviousTotalPages
          if(e.deltaY>0){%
            document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber+1\relax}.svg');%
          }%
        \fi%
        \ifnum\currentPageNumber>1
          if(e.deltaY<0){%
            document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber-1\relax}.svg');%
          }%
        \fi%
      });%
      document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){%
          \ifnum\currentPageNumber<\PreviousTotalPages
            if(e.key=='PageDown'||e.key=='ArrowDown'||e.key=='ArrowRight')%
                document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber+1\relax}.svg');%
          \fi%
          \ifnum\currentPageNumber>1
            if(e.key=='PageUp'||e.key=='ArrowUp'||e.key=='ArrowLeft')%
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{\the\numexpr\currentPageNumber-1\relax}.svg');%
          \fi%
          if(e.key=='Home')
            document.location.replace('\jobname-\zeroPad{\PreviousTotalPages}{1}.svg');%
          if(e.key=='End')
            document.location.replace('\jobname-\PreviousTotalPages.svg');%
        });%
    ]]>%
    </script>%
    </defs>%
  }%
}%
% helper macro \zeroPad : zero-pads integer according to template,
% e. g. 123 --> 00123 if template is `99999`
% #1: arbitrary integer number as template specifying the
%     width, e. g. `987654' for a width of 6 digits
% #2: the number to be formatted
\def\zeroPad#1#2{\zeroPadI{\zeroTemplate{0}{#1}}{#2}}
%low level macros used by \zeroPad
\def\zeroPadI#1#2{% #1: string of zeros specifying width, #2 number
  \ifnum1#2<1#1
    \zeroPadI{#1}{0#2}%
  \else%
    #2%
  \fi%
}%
\def\zeroTemplate#1#2{% create template (string of zeros) from given num
  \ifnum10#1>1#2
    #1%
  \else%
    \zeroTemplate{0#1}{#2}%
  \fi%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%required by PSTricks example
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot,pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\title{Using package \emph{animate} without Adobe}
\subtitle{Use a Web browser and press \framebox{F11}}
\author{AlexG}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Animation}
  trivial example
  \begin{center}
    \begin{animateinline}[controls]{2}
      \multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{\Huge\fbox{\i}}
    \end{animateinline}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  PSTricks example by J. Gilg
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\R{4}            % Radius des festen Kreises (Length fixed Circle)
\def\r{1}            % Radius des abrollenden Kreises (Length rolling Circle)
\def\A{0.75}         % Abstand erzeugenden Punkt zu Mittelpunkt des abrollenden Kreises (Length Pointer)
\def\winkel{360}     % Winkel: 1 Umlauf entspricht 360 (Angle: 1 revolution corresponds to 360)
\FPdiv{\myDeltaA}{\winkel}{90}%

\def\psBall{\rput(0,0){\psSolid[
  object=sphere,r=0.35,
  hue=0 1,
  RotX=\ai\space,ngrid=12](0,0,0)}}

\def\myFigure{%
  \pstVerb{% erzeugender Punkt (parameterized Hypocycloide)
    /Xcoord \ai\space cos \R\space \r\space sub mul \ai\space \R\space \r\space sub \r\space div mul cos \A\space mul add def % (R-r)cos(a)+A cos[(R/r-1) a]
    /Ycoord \ai\space sin \R\space \r\space sub mul \ai\space \R\space \r\space sub \r\space div mul sin \A\space mul sub def % (R-r)sin(a)-A sin[(R/r-1) a]
  }%

  % erzeugender Punkt (generating point)
  \rput(0,0){\rput(!Xcoord Ycoord){\psBall}}%

  \rput(0,0){\psSolid[object=cube,ngrid=4,
     hue=0 1,
     hollow,
     a=0.5,
     RotZ=-\ai\space](0,0,0)%
  }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}[t]{PSTricks Animation}
At the end of a rainbow \dots, by Jürgen Gilg.
\begin{itemize}
  \item best viewed in Blink-based browsers, such as Chromium, Chrome, Opera
  \item frame rate printed to JavaScript console (Ctrl+Shift+I)
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
  \raisebox{0pt}[0.65\height][0pt]{%
  \pstVerb{/clip {} def}% disable `clip' for much better SVG performance in Firefox
  \begin{animateinline}[measure,loop,controls,height=0.8\textheight]{30}
  \multiframe{90}{i=0+1}{%
    \FPeval{ai}{myDeltaA*\i}%
    \begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)\myFigure\end{pspicture}%
  }%
  \end{animateinline}%
}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}\Huge The End\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### 2 Animated SVG as file attachment to PDF

`animate` can export to standalone SVG animations, as outlined in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919 . The SVG can be embedded as a file attachment to the PDF, and be run in a Web browser on click or touch:

```
\usepackage{attachfile} % or attachfile2
...
\textattachfile{animatedImage.svg}{Click!}
```

or without being attached:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
...
\href{run:animatedImage.svg}{Click!}
```

In either case, the operating system/window manager must be configured to use a Web browser as default application for opening SVG files.

Chromium-based Web browsers (e. g. Chrome, Opera) should be used for viewing animated SVG, because of their extremely good rendering performance. The [Lorenz attractor](https://agrahn.gitlab.io) may serve as a test example.

### 3 As for PDF, ...

---

... there is very good news! Open-Source PDF viewers are catching up.

Okular from KDE now supports JavaScript-driven animations. See:

https://community.kde.org/GSoC/2019/StatusReports/Jo%C3%A3oNetto

Tested with Okular-1.10 (KDE-20.04.1)

---

We need an opensource PDF viewer with an opensource JavaScript engine added. All ingredients are there, e.g. Evince, Okular, [JavaScriptCore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore) from webkit.org (used by Apples web browser Safari), [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) (Google Chrome) or [SpiderMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_%28software%29) (Firefox).

[MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/) is a good starting point, but its integrated JavaScript support is quite rudimentary.

And the PDF rendering performance should be high, which is crucial for animations. MuPDF is one rendering library. The other two, Okular, Evince are based on the Poppler library.

The faster one, either MuPDF or Poppler should be chosen.

Someone should take up the challenge and put everything together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll have a look into whether it's possible to implement one of those on their devices :)

Comment: To be clear, you are saying, "there is not **yet** a PDF viewer, other than Adobe, that can correctly display LaTeX animations."  Is this correct?

Comment: @stvn66: Seem to work as well: PDF-XChange, Foxit (all of them closed source though). You may need to try first all three package options `method=icon | widget | ocg`.

Comment: 0@stvn66 Animations most certainly don't worki in Okular, Evince or Chrome browser's integrated PDF viewer. I will give Foxit reader a go since it also has a Linux version which I can hopefully install on my Debian Jessie.

Comment: Just as a side-note: I've just tested `widget` and `ocg` methods, both works fine with PDF-XChange 2.5 (build 315.0). But didn't work with Foxit 7.3.4.311, neither the default `icon` method. All on Windows 10.
I's also managed to run `icon` and `ocg` on Acrobat 6 under Windows XP.

Comment: @G.Bay Among Acrobat Readers, version 7 (on Windows) has had the best performance concerning JS-driven animations so far.

Comment: Interesting answer! I wonder why I had never seen it before! Maybe this technique could also be used for this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455709/animate-package-on-linux-which-pdf-reader

Comment: Of course it can :) I added an answer.

Comment: As for the faster one: MuPDF is faster than Poppler on every benchmark I've seen so far.

Comment: @Skillmon So lets convince Evince and Okular people to make a change and use MuPDF (and add JavaScript).

Comment: @Skillmon Sumatra is MuPDF-based.

Comment: @AlexG so is Zathura.

Comment: Hi! This is a very nice way to deal with the current situation. Do you know if it is also possible to include .eps files in the slides? Cheers!

Comment: @the.polo Yes, as of TL-2019, `dvisvgm` supports EPS and PDF at the same time.

Comment: Option 1 is really interesting! But it's a bit difficult to understand from your example: how does it exactly work? How can someone convert an existing tex file that compiles to PDF into a file that compiles to SVG? What to add in the preamble? Does the command `\animategraphics` need to be redefined/changed? Thank you

Comment: @Tropilio Just compile `svgbeamer.tex` using the commands in the box thereabove. Then open the first slide, `svgbeamer-1.svg`, in Chrome. Use the links in the top-right corner, or PageUp/PageDown on the keyboard. Note that according to the current SVG-1.1 standard,  SVG is a single-page document format and the pages are replaced in the browser window. To prepare your *.tex for SVG, paste and copy the code section between `%%%%` lines into the preamble. Also checkout the new `media4svg` LaTeX package for embedding video: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/media4svg

Comment: @AlexG Hi, thanks for your kind answer. Unfortunately this is not working for me... First it was a bit of a nightmare to have `dvisvgm` working (the option `-p1,-` did not work, but instead `--page=1-` works, fonts are missing etc.). Then, when I finally managed to run the command, the animation created with `\animategraphic` just isn't there... blank, empty, white void.

Comment: @AlexG Ok, I finally got it to work..! I still have a question though: how can I obtain a pdf preview? The `latex` command does not output a pdf file, and the `pdflatex` throws a bunch of errors.

Comment: @AlexG The example svgbeamer.tex did not work for me on Ubuntu 22.04 with TexLive. I had to load the `xfp` package, otherwise I got an `! Undefined Control Sequence` for `\inteval`. Also, cannot compile the PSTricks example. I get the error: `\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks _Not_Configured_For_This_Format` .