# What is the Flash Player alternative for playing embedded videos in a PDF?

Tags: beamer, embedding, adobe, acrobat, video

When Flash Player was still being supported, using LaTeX Beamer for presentations, one was able to compile a PDF with embedded videos/gifs in it (using \includemedia[]). The videos were interactive at least with the simple buttons such as play/pause/repeat. Now Flash Player is no longer supported, and even though the PDF is the same, and you can even continue to compile such PDFs, I can find no way of playing the videos. In Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat, if one tries to click on the embedded video to play it, one gets the following message:

> This content requires Flash Player, which is no longer supported.

Adobe Acrobat gives you a "Learn More" clickable option which then links you to their webpage: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/flash-player-needed-acrobat-reader.html?mv=product&mv2=acrobat. But even that does not seem help; there are alternatives there for Flash Player all right, but I do not see how any of them enables you to play embedded videos on a PDF. What is the actual alternative for opening such PDFs and being able to play the embedded videos therein?

(Note: If I may, to this end, I propose of adding a new tag, involving the words "flash player alternative", in some manner.)

Comment: I think you can find some solutions under [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516029). Moreover, if your video is relatively small/short, you could convert it to gif (extract frames) and use [animate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349100) package, which relies on Javascript.

Comment: @Domen, is it a free (as in freedom) Javascript?

Comment: @Niranjan Well, according to CTAN https://ctan.org/pkg/animate animate uses LPPL.

Comment: @user202729 No; I am not talking about the LaTeX code. I saw that it's pure-TeX and LPPL. I want to know the libraries it relies on. The JavaScript it relies on.

Comment: @Niranjan Okay (according to my understanding) if it includes some nonfree code the author would not be able to distribute it inside the package anyway, and it would be obvious for the user if they manually download the library. In this case there's nothing like that ■ in this particular case I think the necessary JavaScript code is embedded in the TeX file itself, so no external library. https://gitlab.com/agrahn/animate/-/blob/master/animate.sty#L4334

Comment: @user202729 Thanks a lot :) I appreciate your research. I have a last doubt. How is this particular Javascript interpreted? Which software does it need for the interpretation and can that software be run on an entirely free operating system, like say Trisquel GNU/Linux?

Comment: @Niranjan By the viewer? (looks like there are several free-software viewers supporting JavaScript like that [beamer - animate package on Linux - which PDF reader? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455709/animate-package-on-linux-which-pdf-reader) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132087/discussion-between-niranjan-and-user202729).