# Problems to get \animategraphics from animate package working properly in beamer

Tags: beamer, animate

I recently discovered the [`animate`](https://ctan.org/pkg/animate) package (actually it was here, looking for alternatives I came across this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235180/212085) and I want to generate two different versions of my `beamer` slides for a course:

- PDF (with no animation at all if you use free software viewers as I do)
- SVG (with animations, viewing the slides in a browser)

My problems start when I try to get running the most simple example with `\animategraphics` in a `beamer` slide. I am able to get a `standalone` document working ok, the issue arises when using the `beamer` document class. I tried several examples I found with `\animateinline` and they work flawlessly (for example, the `svgbeamer.tex` file that AlexG provides in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235180/212085)... but I can not get it to work with a very simple `\animategraphics` prototype.

For my first example I'm using this public domain annimated gif (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Simple_raycasting_with_fisheye_correction.gif) and after slice it in the corresponding 40 frames with ImageMagick's `convert` (I generated PNG and EPS files to try both LaTeX and XeLaTeX).

Using the minimal template provided by the author in the official doc, I wrote this simple `beamer` example (`example.tex`):

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % already included by beamer
%\usepackage{tikz}     % already included by beamer

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Simple raycasting animation}
    \animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay]{16}{tmp/raycasting_frame}{00}{39}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

then

```bash
latex example
latex example
```

... and the DVI file looks Ok (static, but Ok). Then:

```bash
dvisvgm --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 -p1,- example
```

creates the SVG file and provides this feedback:

```
pre-processing DVI file (format version 2)
processing page 1
  graphic size: 455.24408pt x 256.074799pt (159.999995mm x 89.999998mm)
  output written to example.svg
1 of 1 page converted in 2.84687 seconds
```

However, the animation seems to be "out" of the viewport in the SVG. Only the title of the slide and the controls are visible when rendering the file in the browser, and opening it with Inkscape shows the picture below the slide. Here you can get both files (DVI and SVG) to know what I mean:

- http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/example.dvi
- http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/example.svg

Curiously (or not), if I remove the `dvisvgm` parameter from the document class the final SVG has the picture in the viewport and perform the whole animation just once (and quite fast), but controls do not work. In this case, the picture does not appear in the previous DVI file :-?

UPDATE:

After the kind answers I have just checked the multi-page PDF approach (I'd rather this alternative than using PNG or EPS images) and I do not detect any change when opening the SVG from browser but I can not see now the picture at all when opening it with Inkscape (so I assume it was not been embedded in the SVG, as the file size corroborates).

These are the new files I have generated using the multi-pdf method:

- http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/example2.xdv
- http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/example2.svg

The process now was:

```bash
xelatex -no-pdf example2
xelatex -no-pdf example2
dvisvgm --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 -p1,- example2.xdv
```

`dvisvgm` provided this output:

```
pre-processing DVI file (format version 7)
processing page 1
  graphic size: 455.24408pt x 256.074799pt (159.999995mm x 89.999998mm)
  output written to example2.svg
1 of 1 page converted in 0.283845 seconds
```

The only change in `example.tex` (now `example2.tex`) was the `\animategraphics` invocation:

```
\animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay,width=\linewidth]{16}{tmp/raycasting_frame}{}{}
```

I have also added the output from `dvisvgm` in the previous text (when using `latex` and EPS files instead of `xelatex` and A multi-page PDF).

By the way, I am using TeXLive-2019 (so `dvisvgm` 2.9) in a Debian system.

UPDATE2:

I have updated TeXLive from 2019 to 2020 (I have used Debian experimental packages) and I downloaded and compiled `dvisvgm 2.9.1` (from https://dvisvgm.de)... and that did the trick! (at least for the EPS files approach)

Now the `example.svg` file generated from `example.tex` doing `latex example; latex example; dvisvgm --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 -p1,- example` runs the animation perfectly.

I am still stuck with the multi-page PDF alternative, though. Following @AlexG advice I have added `\usepackage{pdfbase}` to the preamble of `example3.tex` (that is the only difference with `example2.tex`) and after `xelatex -no-pdf example3; xelatex -no-pdf example3; dvisvgm --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 -p1,- example3.xdv` I get these files (I am also attaching the log file):

- http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/example3.log
- http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/example3.xdv
- http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/example3.svg

Comment: Did you try `\begin{frame}[fragile]{Simple raycasting animation}`?

Comment: It works for me, although the animation frames are a bit to wide. So I put option `width=\linewidth`. Which is your `dvisvgm` version? (`dvisvgm --version`). Also note that PNG is not inlined into the SVG code, the image  files remain separate from the SVG. So it is better to convert the GIF to multipage PDF: `convert -coalesce Simple_raycasting_with_fisheye_correction.gif raycasting_frame.pdf`

Comment: With multipage PDF, the inclusion command is `\animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay,width=\linewidth]{16}{tmp/raycasting_frame}{}{}`.

Comment: I see from your `example.svg` that you didn't use  the most recent `dvisvgm-2.9.1`. You are probably still using TeXLive-2019. You will have to wait two days for TeXLive-2020 (to be released on 10th April). Or, if you cannot wait, install the pre-test version: https://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html

Comment: @Toño I tried within a fragile frame as you suggested but I didn't see any change. Thx anyway!

@AlexG Thank you very much for pointing me out the multi-pdf approach. I'd rather this method for my use case (slides in both PDF and SVG). Anyway, I am still not obtaining the animation in the slide... :-?.

So... do you think the new `dvisvgm` in TeXLive-2020 will solve my issue?

Regarding the `width=\linewidth`, I was actually using it before writing the example to paste here.

Thank you very much for your help! (and for your great LaTeX package!)

Comment: @EmilioJ.Padrón You also need `pdfbase.sty`, as of 2020/03/25, which is part of pkg `media9`, version 1.10. There was an issue with this package that lead to the symptoms you describe. However, the fixed version needs dvisvgm-2.9.1, which is only in TeXLive-2020 and in the current MiKTeX.

Comment: @AlexG Updating to dvisvgm-2.9.1 and TeXLive-2020 did the trick for the DVI with EPS files -> SVG approach!

I would like to be able to get the multi-PDF alternative working as well. I have tried adding `\usepackage{pdfbase}` but apparently it did not change anything. I am using TeXLive 2020.20200329 (Debian experimental packages) and `media9.sty` says version is 1.10.

Comment: @EmilioJ.Padrón would you please share the current DVI/XDV file?

Comment: And perhaps, try adding option `type=pdf` to ensure `\animategraphics` indeed uses `tmp/raycasting_frame.pdf`.

Comment: @AlexG Ok Alex, I am attaching the XDV resulting from my last try using `\usepackage{pdfbase}` (and also the log file from XeLaTeX). I am now using the parameter `type=pdf`but I have not noticed any difference, so I assume it is actually using the PDF file. Thanks!

Comment: @EmilioJ.Padrón You are right. There is something wrong with the xelatex + dvisvgm route. Standard latex+dvisvgm works. I will have to investigate. (For now, could you use latex or dvilualatex instead of xelatex?)

Comment: @AlexG Sure, I can arrange it with standard latex for the time being. Thank you very much for your help and for your great work with those packages!

Comment: I found the error. `xcolor`, also loaded by `beamer`, loads the wrong driver file. I am about writing an answer with solution. Just a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `xcolor` (slurped in by `beamer`) loads the wrong driver file `xetex.def` for graphics and color, although `dvisvgm` is passed as a global option to the `beamer` document class. `xcolor` doesn't know about `dvisvgm` and uses `xetex.def` as default.

In order to be able to process the input with `xelatex --no-pdf` for the `dvisvgm` back-end, we enforce `dvips.def` to be used by `xcolor`. `dvips.def` uses the same definitions for colour as `dvisvgm.def`. We can do so by loading `xcolor` with the correct driver option *before* the document class. On the long run, pkg `xcolor` should be updated to be aware of `dvisvgm`.

Then, our multipage PDF `raycasting_frame.pdf` with the animation frames is embedded using the correct low-level commands (`\special`s).

Example code to be compiled with `xelatex --no-pdf` (or another DVI/XDV-making engine) + `dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --font-formt=woff2 --page=- --bbox=papersize`

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Force graphicx/color driver `dvips.def'
\RequirePackage[dvips]{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[dvisvgm,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % already included by beamer
%\usepackage{tikz}     % already included by beamer

\graphicspath{{tmp/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Simple raycasting animation}
    \animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay,width=\linewidth]{16}{raycasting_frame}{}{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Get `raycasting_frame.pdf` from [`Simple_raycasting_with_fisheye_correction.gif`](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Simple_raycasting_with_fisheye_correction.gif) with:

```
convert -coalesce Simple_raycasting_with_fisheye_correction.gif raycasting_frame.pdf
```

Comment: Works flawlesly now! Thanks again @AlexG