# \animategraphics (animate package) and PDFs with rasterized effects result in artifacts

Tags: animations, dvisvgm

Preparing a SVG animated slide from a multi-page PDF with `\animategraphics` (`animate` package) in LaTeX Beamer I find issues with the rasterized effects embedded in the PDF, resulting in artifacts in the resulting SVG.

An example, `test.tex`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                                    
% Force graphicx/color driver `dvips.def'                                      
\RequirePackage[dvips]{xcolor}                                                 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                                    
                                                                               
\documentclass[dvisvgm,aspectratio=169]{beamer}                                
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}                                       
                                                                               
\usepackage{animate}                                                           
%\usepackage{graphicx}                                                         
%\usepackage{tikz}                                                             
                                                                               
\graphicspath{{./}}                                                            
                                                                               
\title{Test}                                                                   
\subtitle{TL;DR}                                                               
                                                                               
\begin{document}                                                               
                                                                               
\begin{frame}{}                                                                
                                                                               
  \animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay,width=.8\linewidth]{1}{all_pages}{}{}
                                                                               
\end{frame}                                                                    
                                                                               
\end{document}
```

The multi-page PDF was created with `pdftk` from multiple PDFs created with `Inkscape`. An example can be found here: [http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/all_pages.pdf](http://gac.udc.es/%7Eemilioj/all_pages.pdf)

From the LaTeX file a xdv file is obtained by:

```
xelatex --no-pdf test.tex
xelatex --no-pdf test.tex
```

and the final SVG is generated with:

```
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff2 --page=- --bbox=papersize test.xdv
```

An example of the obtained SVG: [http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/test.svg](http://gac.udc.es/%7Eemilioj/test.svg) ([http://gac.udc.es/~emilioj/test.log](http://gac.udc.es/%7Eemilioj/test.log))

I am using `TeX Live` 2020.20210202 and `dvisvgm` 2.11.1 in a Debian Sid system and I tried the `animate` package included in my TeX Live (2020/10/07) as well the last release from git (2021/06/11).

Comment: probably not related but why do you force dvips for the colors if you use xelatex?

Comment: Hi! It is definitely a good question! That is a workaround as xcolor is not dvisvgm aware: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537711/212085

Comment: ah, well with a current latex you could try `\makeatletter
\declare@file@substitution{xetex.def}{dvisvgm.def}
\makeatother` , this will force xetex to load the dvisvgm.def instead (but I don't know if the driver is better for your use case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATE***

As Martin states in his comment, this is a limitation of the PostScript format, which does not support transparency in bitmaps and which is an intermediate step during PDF to SVG conversion.

To work around this limitation, a Perl script is proposed that converts black colour to transparency in embedded bitmaps. The script requires embedded bitmaps to be in PNG format. Since, by default, `dvisvgm` converts bitmapped content into JPEG, option `--bitmap-format=png16m` must be added.

The Perl script makes use of the `Image::Magick` and `MIME::Base64` modules. Hopefully both are already present on your system. Otherwise, they need to be installed. For `Image::Magick` follow the instructions given [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php).

First of all, make sure bitmap data are embedded as PNG:

```bash
latex test.tex # or xelatex --no-pdf test.tex
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff2 --page=- --bbox=papersize --bitmap-format=png16m test.dvi # or test.xdv
```

Then, run the script on the `dvisvgm` output:

```bash
svgtransparency.pl test.svg > test-fixed.svg
```

---

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

#######################################################################
# converts black colour in embedded PNG data to transparent in SVG
#
# fixes transparency issue reported in 
#
#     https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605587
#
# usage:
#
# dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --font-format=woff2 --page=- --bbox=papersize --bitmap-format=png16m test.dvi
#
# svgtransparency.pl test.svg > test-fixed.svg
#
#######################################################################

use MIME::Base64;
use Image::Magick;

$ispng=0;
$pngdata='';
$image=Image::Magick->new(magick=>'png');

while(<>){
  print unless ($ispng);
  if (/data:image\/png;base64,$/) {$ispng=1;next;}
  if ($ispng) {
      $pngdata .= (/^(.*?)(\'\/>)?$/)[0];
      if (/\'\/>$/){
        $pngdata=decode_base64($pngdata);
        $image->BlobToImage($pngdata);
        $image->Transparent(color=>'black');
        $pngdata=($image->ImageToBlob())[0];
        $pngdata=encode_base64($pngdata);
        print "$pngdata'/>\n";
        @$image=();
        $pngdata='';
        $ispng=0;
      }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reviewing the issue @AlexG!

Comment: Wait, I am going to prepare a Perl-script to convert black to transparency. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: That's a limitation of PostScript which doesn't support alpha channels in image data. So, PS images are always opaque. Since dvisvgm's PDF support relies on Ghostscript that in turn internally converts PDF to PS, dvisvgm has no access to any transparency information when extracting the bitmap data. Unfortunately, there isn't much I can do here.

Comment: No problem, this can be done in a post-processing step. And thank you for your input!

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexG for your kind help! Your perl script works like a champ postprocessing the transparencies in the final SVG :-) Really appreciate it!