# Conflict between exerquiz and animate: no preview

Tags: animate, acrotex

Since my last update of Texlive, I have conflict when loading animate and exerquiz in the same document: the document compiles, the animation plays well in Acrobat, but when I open the pdf with another reader (evince, okular,...) that do not support animations, I have only a white rectangle in place of my animation, instead of the first frame.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{animate}
%\usepackage{exerquiz} % uncomment this line and the animation preview disappear

\begin{document}

Watch this counter:\begin{animateinline}[loop,autoplay,poster=0,controls]{2}
    \multiframe{10}{in=0+1}{%
        \fbox{\in}
    }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this MWE, and open it in evince, I see the counter 0 in the fbox, and the controls beneath.

When I uncomment the `\usepackage{exerquiz}` line and compile this MWE, and open it with evince, I see nothing except "Watch this counter:"; but in Acrobat the animation still plays.

This did not happen before I updated Texlive; I always saw the first frame in evince. How can I restore the old behaviour?

Comment: Strange observation: when I open with evince a pdf file generated 3 months ago in the same conditions, the animation preview doesn't display; while it did 3 months ago. So it is not a question of Texlive update. Is this problem related to the end of Flash support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point in the loading chain of packages, `hyperref` is invoked in a way that puts the key `/NeedAppearances true` in the `AcroForm` dictionary of the PDF Catalog. `NeedAppearances` is declared deprecated in the current ISO PDF-2.0 standard.

Also, `animate` and `hyperref` concurrently want to write the `Fields` entry in the `AcroForm` dictionary, if `hyperref`'s `Form` environment is set (implicitly done by `exerquiz`).

The following fix suppresses `NeedAppearances` in the PDF output and hooks into `hyperref`'s mechanism of Form field registration:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{exerquiz}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Fix compatibility with hyperref Forms %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
% suppress deprecated /NeedAppearances true|false
\HyField@NeedAppearancesfalse
% hook into hyperref's Form Field registration
\cs_set_protected_nopar:Nn\pbs_appendtofields:n{
  \tl_gput_left:Nx\HyField@afields{#1\space}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Watch this counter:\begin{animateinline}[loop,autoplay,controls]{2}
    \multiframe{10}{in=0+1}{%
        \fbox{\in}
    }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, but I was too quick to say it worked. Now, I have good preview in Evince, but no more animation in Acrobat.

Comment: @JPG Now it works again in AcroRead.

Comment: (Okular still fails to play; it seems to choke on some document-level JavaScript introduced by `exerquiz`.)

Comment: Yes it now works again; thanks. I tried with Okular and... surprise! My animation plays! What? Okular can now play animated PDF? Did anyone knew that?

Comment: @JPG See: https://community.kde.org/GSoC/2019/StatusReports/Jo%C3%A3oNetto

Comment: Good new, I missed your edit in [Using the animate package without Adobe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235139/using-the-animate-package-without-adobe?noredirect=1&lq=1)