# Beamer and SVG questions: attaching to a pdf and real full screen

Tags: beamer, animate, svg

I'm using @AlexG's method described here [Using the animate package without Adobe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235139/using-the-animate-package-without-adobe/235180#235180) to produce an animated svg (animate package and/or tikz animations library), it's really nice. I have two questions:

1- I would like to attach the .svg to a pdf file as explained in the link but I'm not sure what I should use to compile. Up to now I was using: xelatex -no-pdf svgbeamer.tex && xelatex -no-pdf svgbeamer.tex && dvisvgm --font-format=ttf --exact --zoom=-1 -p1,- svgbeamer.xdv

2- When in full screen mode (F11) my slides don't occupy the whole screen. Using tikz I draw a rectangle (width 16cm, height 9cm) and put everything I want on screen inside it but I still get white bands above, below and to the left of the rectangle. Is there a way around this?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,animations,arrows,backgrounds,patterns,intersections,tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\huge

\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (16,9); % a 16 by 9 rectangle
\clip (0,0) rectangle (16,9); % everything outside the rectangle is clipped 

%%%%%%%% GRID
\foreach \i in {1,...,20}{\draw[gray] (\i*0.8,0) -- (\i*0.8,9);  }
\foreach \i in {0,...,11}{ 
\draw[gray] (0,0.2+\i*0.8) -- (17,0.2+\i*0.8); 
\foreach \j in {1,...,3}{\draw[lightgray, thin] (0,0.2+\i*0.8 + \j*0.2) -- (17,0.2+\i*0.8+ \j*0.2);}
}
%%%%%%%%%

\draw (8,8.2) node[text width=14.4cm, align=left, anchor=base] 
{This is a test}; % some text

\draw[very thick] (2,6) -- (4,3) -- (1,4) -- cycle; % some drawing 

\draw[very thick] (12,6) -- (18,3) -- (11,4) -- cycle; % some clipped drawing 


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and what it looks like after pressing F11:

[image]

Comment: For your second part, can you share a minimal working example so we can see how you position your rectangle on the slide?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE!

Comment: I just added a minimal example

Comment: Do you want to produce the *whole* presentation in SVG format, as suggested in **1** of the linked answer, or a standalone animation in SVG format attached to a PDF, as in **2**? In the latter case, the animation is shown in a web browser window that opens when you click on the file attachment in the PDF viewer. Also, in that case, it does not make sense to use a presentation document class (`beamer`) for the standalone animation. Please clarify.

Comment: @AlexG I have already succeeded in producing the whole presentation following your method number 1. Ideally I would now like to attach the whole presentation to a PDF so I only have a single file to send for example. The idea would be to make PDF really portable.

Comment: I'd put all SVGs in a ZIP archive and send that one.

Comment: @Alex G thank you for your answer. I have one more questions: is there a way to modify the hotkey for fullscreen? I'm asking because I'm not sure how you can get fullscreen on a mobile device (ipad...) since you can't press F11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of your question:

Normally `tikzpictures` are placed within the normal text area, so the space to the left is the normal text margin of a beamer slide. As a hacky solution you could cancel the margin with

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0cm}
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks

Comment: @FunkiePhil You're welcome!

Comment: @FunkiePhil If you find an answer useful, you should vote for it. And as the asker you can also accept exactly one answer as the one you are using. Please have a look into [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the [Help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help).