# Combining BEAMER frames/slides and TIKZ animations

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations, svg

I'm using the method described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235139/using-the-animate-package-without-adobe/235180#235180) to produce a presentation in SVG format. Ideally I would like some frames to contain multiple slides (using <1->,<2->... for example) some of which would play an animation (I use TIKZ's animations library). I am struggling to find a way to trigger such an animation with the beginning of a slide: basically I get all the animations in the frame starting at once(which again is not the point).
Has anyone succeded in creating a frame consisting of a sequence (triggered) of slides, some static, some animated?

Here is a minimal example with 4 text blocks and two animated arrows. When using ArrowDown to navigate to slide 2, the first animation is played a second time (along with the second animation).

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,animations,arrows,backgrounds,patterns,intersections,tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
    
    
    %%%%%%% SO TIKZMARK WORKS WITH XETEX
    \makeatletter
    \def\pgfsys@hboxsynced#1{%
      {%
        \pgfsys@beginscope%
        \setbox\pgf@hbox=\hbox{%
          \hskip\pgf@pt@x%
          \raise\pgf@pt@y\hbox{%
            \pgf@pt@x=0pt%
            \pgf@pt@y=0pt%
            \special{pdf: content q}%
            \pgflowlevelsynccm%
            \pgfsys@invoke{q -1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm}%
            \special{pdf: content -1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm q}% translate to original coordinate system
            \pgfsys@invoke{0 J [] 0 d}% reset line cap and dash
            \wd#1=0pt%
            \ht#1=0pt%
            \dp#1=0pt%
            \box#1%
            \pgfsys@invoke{n Q Q Q}%
          }%
          \hss%
        }%
        \wd\pgf@hbox=0pt%
        \ht\pgf@hbox=0pt%
        \dp\pgf@hbox=0pt%
        \pgfsys@hbox\pgf@hbox%
        \pgfsys@endscope%
      }%
    }
    \makeatother
    
    %%%%%%% NAVIGATION WITH ARROWUP AND ARROWDOWN
    
    \usepackage[totpages]{zref}
    \usepackage{atbegshi}
    \usepackage{fontawesome}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \AtBeginShipout{%
      \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
        \special{dvisvgm:raw
          <defs>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          <![CDATA[
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
              if(e.key=='ArrowDown'){
                \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages
                  document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg');%
                \fi
              }else if(e.key=='ArrowUp'){
                \ifnum\thepage>1
                  document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg');%
                \fi%
              }
            });
          ]]>
          </script>
          </defs>
        }%
      }%
     
    }%
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    
    \huge
    
    \draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (16,9);
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (16,9);
    
    %%%%%%% 1st slide
    \begin{onlyenv}<1->
    
    \draw (4,8) node[text width=7.2cm, align=left, anchor=base] 
    {Some text\subnode[inner sep=0pt]{a}{.}};
    
    \draw (12,8) node[text width=7.2cm, align=left, anchor=base] 
    {\subnode[inner sep=0pt]{b}{A}nd then some...};
    
    
    \draw[thick,->] :rotate = {base = "90",0s="90", 1s="0", forever, origin = {(0,0)}}  (a) --(b)  ;
    
    \end{onlyenv}
    
    %%%%%%% 2nd slide
    \begin{onlyenv}<2->
    
    \draw (4,6) node[text width=7.2cm, align=left, anchor=base] 
    {And so on \subnode[inner sep=0pt]{c}{.}};
    
    \draw (12,6) node[text width=7.2cm, align=left, anchor=base] 
    {\subnode[inner sep=0pt]{d}{.}.. and so forth...};
    
    
    \draw[thick,->] :rotate = {base = "90",0s="90", 1s="0", forever, origin = {(0,0)}}  (c) --(d)  ;
    
    \end{onlyenv}
    
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

This is compiled using

```
xelatex -no-pdf svgbeamer.tex && xelatex -no-pdf svgbeamer.tex && dvisvgm --font-format=ttf --exact --zoom=-1 -p1,- svgbeamer.xdv
```

I guess this is because on each slide the timeline is reset to 0. So, ideally, I would like to find a way to make a single slide with an animation that can be paused (using a key for instance).

Comment: Please add a minimal working example to your question that reproduces your problem with all animations starting at once

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
 it took me some time to get back in front of a computer but I've added a minimal working example