# Hypertex option and borders

Tags: svg, hyperlink, dvisvgm

Using the answer of AlexG to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235139/using-the-animate-package-without-adobe), I have the following example code (example.tex), which has to be compiled with

```
latex example
latex example
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --bbox=papersize --zoom=-1 -p1,- --output=%f-%1p example
```

example.tex file :

```tex
\documentclass[dvisvgm,hypertex,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{animate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PageDown, PageUp key event handling; navigation symbols
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[totpages]{zref}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
    \special{dvisvgm:raw
      <defs>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <![CDATA[
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
          if(e.key=='PageDown'){
            \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg');%
            \fi
          }else if(e.key=='PageUp'){
            \ifnum\thepage>1
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg');%
            \fi%
          }
        });
      ]]>
      </script>
      </defs>
    }%
  }%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{%
    \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
      \normalsize\color{structure!40!}%
      \ifnum\thepage>1%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \else%  
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowLeft}%  
      \fi\hspace{0.5ex}%
      \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg}{\faArrowRight}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowRight}%  
      \fi%
      \hspace{0.5ex}%
    }}%
  }%  
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Using package \emph{animate} without Adobe}
\subtitle{Use a Web browser and press \framebox{F11}}
\author{AlexG}
\date{\today}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sommaire}
 \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame} 
}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}{Animation}
  trivial example
  \begin{center}
    \begin{animateinline}[controls]{2}
      \multiframe{10}{i=0+1}{\Huge\fbox{\i}}
    \end{animateinline}  
  \end{center}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}\Huge The End\end{center}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces an svg list of documents that can then be used in a browser (by the way, great answer AlexG, thanks !). Now, it seems that the hypertex option (which is needed to produce the navigation symbols on each slide) adds borders to each of the hypertext lines in the document (that's the case of the "First Section" in the second slide of the document). Is there a way to get rid of the borders but keeping the navigation symbols ? This would mean having only the arrows, and not their borders.

Comment: You can use dvisvgm option [`--linkmark`](https://dvisvgm.de/Manpage/#opt-linkmark) to change the appearance of the link markers. `--linkmark=none` hides them completely.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, it works !