# Animategraphics, beamer and svg outputs

Tags: beamer, animate, svg, dvisvgm

I am trying to adapt the answer of AlexG to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661378/hypertex-option-and-borders?noredirect=1#comment1645243_661378) in order to get a beamer presentation which includes an animation.

The problem is that I use some personnalized beamer theme slide and for some reason a part of the slide is destroyed when I follow this procedure.

The files of my personnalized theme and the pdf images that I use in the latex code below are all [available here](https://cloud.ljll.math.upmc.fr/owncloud/index.php/s/7aEEEScT9LIGfIR).

Here's an example of .tex file which works fine with pdflatex :

```tex
\documentclass[dvisvgm,hypertext,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{wamclassic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PageDown, PageUp key event handling; navigation symbols
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[totpages]{zref}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
    \special{dvisvgm:raw
      <defs>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <![CDATA[
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
          if(e.key=='PageDown'){
            \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg');%
            \fi
          }else if(e.key=='PageUp'){
            \ifnum\thepage>1
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg');%
            \fi%
          }
        });
      ]]>
      </script>
      </defs>
    }%
  }%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{%
    \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
      \normalsize\color{jolijaune}%
      \ifnum\thepage>1%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \else%  
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowLeft}%  
      \fi\hspace{0.5ex}%
      \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg}{\faArrowRight}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowRight}%  
      \fi%
      \hspace{0.5ex}%
    }}%
  }%  
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



  \title{\hspace{1.5cm} Name -- Title of the talk}

\institute{LJLL, Sorbonne Université}


  \begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First slide}
\begin{center}
  This beamer style will be destroyed.
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Destroyed}
  \vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{\animategraphics[loop,controls]{30}{image}{1}{2}}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Destroyed}
  \vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{\animategraphics[loop,controls]{30}{image_small}{1}{2}}
\vfill
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With the previous code and using pdflatex, the animation is included in a proper way :

[image]

However, if I replace the first line of the tex file above by

```tex
\documentclass[dvisvgm,hypertext,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
```

and compile it with (as suggested by AlexG in the post cited above)

```
latex example
latex example
dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --bbox=papersize --zoom=-1 -p1,- --output=%f-%1p example
```

The result can then be looked on a browser (I use Chromium) ; unfortunately a part of the slide is then missing. The line below with name, title and date disappear and also the arrows in the upper right part ; it seems that all the beamer layer as been erased :

[image]

I tried playing with the size of the animategraphics command but whatever I try, it's even getting worse ! I also tried reducing the image's size (that's the purpose of the image_small* files), it does not solve the issue. Strangely enough it seems even worse (and a part of the image itself seems to be destroyed, the horizontal line above is gray). Any clue ? Playing with the size of the animategraphics seems tricky ...

[image]

Comment: Is your custom theme available somewhere for download?

Comment: @samcarter The link is provided in the OP

Comment: @AlexG Thanks! I did not see the link.

Comment: Your example works for me in both SVG and PDF output. I suspect Ghostscript to be the culprit. The newest version 10.0 released a few weeks ago is not compatible with `dvisvgm`. The author of `dvisvgm` is working on it or has already fixed the problem. Can you check which GS version you have? `gs --version`

Comment: I have the 9.50 one

Comment: Which TeX distro and which OS do you use? MikTeX or TeXLive, Linux or ...?

Comment: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian), on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: This is rather old. Could you install TeXLive-2022? (Parallel install as a normal user is possible.)

Comment: I just tried, I get exactly the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139819/discussion-between-alexg-and-xounamoun).